# How do I declare a Jagged array of 2 dimensions?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I m trying to declare a 2D dynamic array below is my code:

```
   var marray= new[,]
                        {
                            {
                                "1", 
                                "Module 1.1",
                                "Module 1.2",
                                " Module 1.3",
                                "Module 1.4",
                                "Module 1.5"
                            },

                            {
                                "2", 
                                "Module 2.1"                                    
                            }
                        };
```

I am getting error on second value  **"An array initializer of '6' is expected"**.
I  can understant it is expecting 2nd to be having 6 values but I need it to be dynamic of any length.
 I dont know much about array so cannot resolve it. Can you please guide. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're receiving the compile error because your sub-array sizes are not equivalent. You'll either need to implement this using [jagged arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) as [Mitch Wheat suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18604346/635634) *or* ensure that all elements in the sub-array have the same number of elements.

Comment: thanks, can u Please also guide how to initilize jagged array as I am not sure about the length of my arrays. Please guide

Comment: Jagged arrays are generally static. To initialize it dynamically you should use a dynamic data structure (like `List<T>`). That is different enough from this question that I'd recommend asking a new question for it.

Answer (score 6):

You want a **ragged** array rather than a *straight* multi-dimensional array because your sub-array sizes are not the same.

Declare as

```
var marray= new[][]
```

rather than

```
var marray= new[,]
```

Refs:

- [Jagged Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)
- [Multidimensional Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)

Comment: @Mitch thanks. But how to initialize Jagged array, it would be dynamic. Please guide

Comment: Your posted code is not dynamic. That might be a different question.

Comment: @MitchWheat can you please guide me here as I dont have code to ask. Thanks for this.

Comment: I think your best course of action is to accept an answer and ask a separate question.